# Correct way to manage an observable with services in angular

Tags: angular, observable

I have a doubt and I need to listen to some pro-angular-user to get the right way to manage this task. I've found tons of opinions about subscribe and async pipe and now I'm more confused then before.

Task: I have a list of topics in homepage. In another page I add/remove topics routine. When I came back to homepage I want that this list is updated. I use a service to manage this stuff.

This is an example code:

**Home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TopicService } from '../services/topic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
   
  topics:any; 

  constructor(private topicService: topicService){ }
 
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getTopics();
  }
  
  //here the first doubt using subscribe, I omit onDestroy with unsubscribe (it's prefered to do with async pipe in view?)
  getTopics(){
    this.topicService.getTopic().subscribe(topics =>{
      this.topics = topics;
    });
  }

}
```

**Home.page.html**

```
...
          <ion-segment-button value="{{topic.id}}" *ngFor="let topic of topics?.data">
            <ion-label>{{topic.title}}</ion-label>
          </ion-segment-button>
...
```

**settings.page.ts**

```
...

  topics:any

  addTopic(topic): Observable<any> {
    return this.topicService.addTopic(topic).subscribe((result)=>{
    this.topics.push(result)
    });
  }

  removeTopic(topic): Observable<any> {
    return this.topicService.removeTopic(topic).subscribe((result)=>{
    this.topics.filter(...)
    });
  }
...
```

**topicService.ts**

```
   topics: Observable<any>;

   getTopics(): Observable<any>{
    this.http.get('/topics').pipe(
    map(result => {
       this.topics.next(result);
     })
    );
   }

   addTopic(topic){
    this.http.post('/topics/add/', {topic} ).pipe(
    map(result => {
       this.topics.next(result);
     })
    );
   }

   removeTopic(topic){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... Question about async pipe in angular is too general. Personally I prefer it over subscribe for better readability, and in some cases you don't have to handle "unsubscribe" manually. Angular HTTPClient service emits "complete" so you don't have to manually unsubscribe. In your case it's not much different than promise, but by utilizing power of Observables you have more control over your incoming data and if you ask me - much cleaner syntax.

Now about correctness of your code. It's almost good but... The `topic` variable in `settings.page.ts` is obsolete, you're not subscribing to it anywhere in your code. Also `pip(map())` operator should return value, but I will refer to this later.

So first I would change this unnecessary `topics: Observable<any>;` variable, that require manual subscription handle, and simply return http observable from functions like this:

**topicService.ts**

```
getTopics(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get('/topics');
}

addTopic(topic){
  return this.http.post('/topics/add/', {topic} );
}
```

At least from the code you've provided `pipe(map(...))` operation was obsolete, and was used incorrectly. The correct way would be to use `pipe(map(...))` to modify incoming stream data. Check out official documentation for more details: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map

And in this case your `Home.page.ts` should be done this way:

```
topics:any; 

constructor(private topicService: topicService){ }
 
ngOnInit(){
   this.topicService.getTopic().subscribe(topics =>{
      this.topics = topics;
   });
}
```

Also you could use map to return only "necessary" data if your server API packs response with some "unnecessary" meta.

So in your case instead of manually checking if `topics` variable has `.data` property, you could handle this in your service/controller(.component.ts). So once again we might modify our `topicService.ts`

```
getTopics(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get('/topics').pipe(map(_topicRes => _topicRes.data));
}
```

In this case `map` operator will "modify" our HTTP response to only return `data` property, and of course everything inside `data`, so your `Home.page.html` could look like this:

```
<ion-segment-button value="{{topic.id}}" *ngFor="let topic of topics">
   <ion-label>{{topic.title}}</ion-label>
</ion-segment-button>
```

Anyway, as I've said before -> it all depends on a use case. Play with it, experiment, do some dummy-apps. In time, you will know. Check out some demo projects online.

You should try and resolve data from API by route param like /article/:id. This should be a good practice for you - keyworld: `switchMap` :) Good luck.